# Spring Web Security Config - Ignore CSRF Validation for either or

Tags: spring, csrf

I have certain conditions to ignore csrf validations but I am not sure how to put this in config. Following are my conditions to ignore the validation:

- Has a `Bearer` token in the authorization.

Or

- Particular URL

Here is the config I have now:

```
security.csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization")).ignoringAntMatchers("/test").and();
```

But with this config, I guess it is treating it like an AND operation or something. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `OrRequestMatcher.`

```
security.csrf()
       .ignoringRequestMatchers(new OrRequestMatcher(new RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("Authorization"), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/test")));
```